# Clicking Run and debug buttons raise NullPointerException inside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I can't run any of my projects as clicking on the `run` or `debug` buttons (or pressing their respective shortcut keys) will raise the following NPE and ask me to report it to google.

This error happens inside Android Studio, not on my code; an example code is not needed to reproduce, as it can happen with any project.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.findFileByIoFile(LocalFileSystemBase.java:79)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtil.findFileByIoFile(VfsUtil.java:232)
at com.android.tools.idea.model.ManifestInfo$ManifestFile.getLibManifests(ManifestInfo.java:406)
at com.android.tools.idea.model.ManifestInfo$ManifestFile.refresh(ManifestInfo.java:339)
at com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.syncWithReadPermission(MergedManifest.java:377)
at com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest$2.run(MergedManifest.java:356)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:843)
at com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.sync(MergedManifest.java:353)
at com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.getActivities(MergedManifest.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.activity.DefaultActivityLocator.lambda$computeDefaultActivity$0(DefaultActivityLocator.java:79)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService$1.run(DumbService.java:89)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService$2.compute(DumbService.java:125)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService$2.compute(DumbService.java:119)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:859)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:119)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:86)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.activity.DefaultActivityLocator.computeDefaultActivity(DefaultActivityLocator.java:78)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.activity.DefaultActivityLocator.validate(DefaultActivityLocator.java:65)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DefaultActivityLaunch$State.checkConfiguration(DefaultActivityLaunch.java:49)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfiguration.checkConfiguration(AndroidRunConfiguration.java:108)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.validate(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:175)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.checkConfiguration(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:113)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.checkSettings(RunnerAndConfigurationSettingsImpl.java:423)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.canRunConfiguration(RunManagerImpl.java:535)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunManagerImpl.canRunConfiguration(RunManagerImpl.java:530)
at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:71)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:117)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$300(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:67)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:509)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:222)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just noticed that Java wasn't running on my machine. That was the root of the problem.

I have a Macbook pro and when I run Android Studio, Java's icon will get added to the docker. I don't know why it didn't start automatically this time, very strange. Therefore, I had to press on sync project (although the project was already synced) just to force Java to run! Then, the usual icon was added to docker and everything was working properly!

Comment: Works great. Thx

Comment: Had the same problem. I just clicked Make Project: Ctrl+F9

Answer (score 5):

Had similar issues, but it was because I had the build variant set to “release” while trying to debug on a physical device.  Switched to “debug” and all started running smoothly again.